# unflatten a python dictionary in an efficient way

Tags: python, dictionary

assume you have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
{'id':1,
'station': 'LYO',
'country': 'France',
'classes': 'EU',
'label': 'LYO CS',
'color': 'orange',
'population':100000,
'university':yes}
```

I would like to create:

```
{'data':{'id':1,
        'station': 'LYO',
        'country': 'France'},
'classes': 'EU',
'label': 'LYO CS',
'color': 'orange',
'population':100000,
'university':yes}
```

basically include in data subdictionary the key-values of data_items= ['id','station','country']

the obvious long way to do that is:

```
data_keys = ['id','station']
data_sub_dict = {'data':{el:node[el] for el in data_keys}}
rest_sub_dict = {el:node[el] for el in node.keys() if el not in data_keys}
dict_result ={}
dict_result.update(data_sub_dict)
dict_result.update(rest_sub_dict)
```

This is ok, but it smells to me as not very pythonic.

Would you do it otherwise? (more compacted?, other ways to do it?)

thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: you could shorten the last three lines: `dict_result = {**data_sub_dict,**rest_sub_dict}`

Comment: I wouldn't focus on writing the most "compacted" code possible. Readability is much more valuable than code compactness. Would you prefer to debug some clearly written functionality or as much as possible logic written on just one line?

Comment: @JLeno46 I have the impression that the code can be much better. not just nicer.

Comment: @Marc. voila!!! that's what I was looking for. perfect for readability. And perfect compacted. Because this can be used also when there are other dictionaries to "add up".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `update`s?

It's possible to write all in one instruction using `dict` constructor:

```py
data = {'id':1,
'station': 'LYO',
'country': 'France',
'classes': 'EU',
'label': 'LYO CS',
'color': 'orange',
'population':100000,
'university':'yes'}


dict(
    {'data': {k:v for k,v in data.items() if k in ('id', 'station','country')}},
    **{k:v for k,v in data.items() if k in ('classes', 'color', 'population', 'university')})
```

Result:

```
{'data': {'id': 1, 'station': 'LYO', 'country': 'France'},
 'classes': 'EU',
 'color': 'orange',
 'population': 100000,
 'university': 'yes'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a function that splits a dictionary into two, while providing a list of keys:

```
def filterByKeys(d,keys):
    a={}; b={};
    for k in d:
        if k in keys: a[k] = d[k]
        else :        b[k] = d[k]
    return (a,b)
    
d1, d2 = filterByKeys(d,['id','station'])
{'data':d1,**d2}
```

While this approach does not use list comprehension for iterating the dictionary, it becomes very easy to understand.

Comment: Any reason you're passing `keys` as a list instead of a set?

Comment: not at all. actually perhaps set its better. I am simply not a strong-set-user

Comment: Mostly out of habit. Performance wise sets are slightly better choice, especially wrt to duplicates. Do you have another reason to prefer a set?

Comment: No reason except that sets are specifically designed to be good at `in` operations.  It's the Pythonic thing to do.